# SignalR OnConnected method not firing when multiple users sign in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, asp.net-identity, signalr-hub

I have been trying to add a real-time notification feature to an MVC website using SignalR. I am using Asp.NET Identity for authentication.

As I understood from [SignalR documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#terminology) the OnConnected method on Hub class should fire whenever a user logs in.

So when I came to debug, if I sign the first user, the OnConnected method called properly. However, when I open another browser(eg: Firefox, Microsoft edge ..) and sign in another user, OnConnected is never called.

My Startup class looks like this:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(NotificationApp.Startup))]
namespace NotificationApp
{
  public partial class Startup
  {
      public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
      {
          ConfigureAuth(app);
          app.MapSignalR();
      }
  }
}
```

Hub class

```
namespace NotificationApp
{    
    [Authorize]
    public class NotificationHub : Hub {
        
        //This gets called for the first logged in user only
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).connected(Context.ConnectionId);

            return base.OnConnected();
        }

       public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
            return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
        }
   }
}
```

Client code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var notificationHub = $.connection.notificationHub;
    
    //Called for every client properly
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

     console.log('Notification hub started');
      
    });

 //This gets called for the first logged in user only
 notificationHub.client.connected = function (message) {

        console.log('Hello' + message);
    };

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open another tab, you are the same client and are then given a connectionID.

Try changing "Client":

```
        public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).connected(Context.ConnectionId);

        return base.OnConnected();
    }
```

To "Caller":

```
        public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        Clients.Caller.connected(Context.ConnectionId);

        return base.OnConnected();
    }
```

Also, move your client function before your hub.start. You should always register one function before your start. See the note regarding in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#establishconnection).

Comment: Thank you so much. The issue occurred mainly because of my client code.